# C# Datetime wildcard

Tags: c#, datetime

I am trying to write a program that will take a text file (a log file) and grab the last 10 lines of it to match with a specific log entry and if it doesn't match throw an error. The problem is these log entries are datetime stamped depending on when a specific task is run.

An example of the entry I am trying to match up is

```
Started MM/DD/YY HH:MM:SS
Download1 - success 
Download2 - success
Download3 - success
Download4 - success
Download5 - success
Download6 - success
Download7 - success
Download8 - success
Ended MM/DD/YY HH:MM:SS
```

As this should be the latest entry in the log file when we run this program, I have used the following code to match a sample success log with what is in the specified log file (slightly edited for simplicity):

```
if (logfile.EndsWith("Started MM/DD/YY HH:MM:SS
                      Download1 - success 
                      Download2 - success
                      Download3 - success
                      Download4 - success
                      Download5 - success
                      Download6 - success
                      Download7 - success
                      Download8 - success
                      Ended MM/DD/YY HH:MM:SS")
    {
           Console.WriteLine("Program Was Successful");
    }
else
    { 
           Console.WriteLine("Error");
    }
```

The problem I have is that the datetime stamp will never match up to my sample successful log as this task is run on multiple computers throughout the nation, with different time zones, etc.

I was wondering if and how I can edit the sample success log for when we match up the matching code will disregard the date/time stamp. Is there a way to write a date/time wildcard? Any help is always appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Since you do not need to know the date (just if its there), you can simply use a regex.

Comment: Hmm. I've never played around with regex's before, but there's always a first. I'll look into this. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it is just enough to compare with:

1 - the first line must starts with "Started"

2 - the last line must starts with "Ended"

3 - all lines between first and last lines must ends with "success"

```
    {
        var text = @"Started MM/DD/YY HH:MM:SS
Download1 - success
Download2 - success
Download3 - success
Download4 - success
Download5 - success
Download6 - success
Download7 - success
Download8 - success
Ended MM/DD/YY HH:MM:SS";

        var result = IsValid(text, 8);  // you can set the number of "Download.." strings
    }
```

...

```
    private static bool IsValid(string text, int countOfDownloads)
    {
        string[] lines = text.Split(new[] {Environment.NewLine}, StringSplitOptions.None);
        return IsValid(lines,  countOfDownloads);
    }

    private static bool IsValid(string[] lines, int countOfDownloads)
    {
        if (lines.Length != countOfDownloads + 2)
            return false;

        if (!lines[0].StartsWith("Started"))
            return false;

        if (!lines[lines.Length - 1].StartsWith("Ended"))
            return false;

        for (var i = 1; i <= countOfDownloads; i++)
        {
            if (!lines[i].Trim().EndsWith("success"))
                return false;
        }

        return true;
    }
```